# How to accommodate multiple HAVING clauses within the same SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have been having trouble making my query work and was hoping for assistance.  At a high level, I am trying to query a table of users and return results based on a set of criteria + plus the fact that the users are within a specified mile radius OR also return results of users with the same specified criteria and ignoring the mile radius requirement.

The 'specified criteria' I speak of above is

```
u.activated = 1 AND u.type LIKE ('%red%')
```

Here is my query which I know doesn't work the way I'd like

```
SELECT u.online, u.total_spend, u.name, u.address, u.city, u.state, u.zip, u.type,
    u.activated, ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 42.459080 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( u.lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( u.lng ) - RADIANS( - 83.934013 ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( 42.459080 ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( u.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance,
    t.username, COUNT( t.active ) AS reviews
FROM testimonials AS t
RIGHT JOIN users AS u ON ( t.username = u.username ) 
WHERE u.activated =1
AND u.type LIKE (
'%red%'
)
AND (
u.online =1
OR u.online =0
)
GROUP BY IFNULL( t.username, UUID( ) ) 
HAVING distance <  '15'
ORDER BY total_spend DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I realize that the HAVING operator works on the data already pulled which is where the issue lies.  What I don't understand is how to pull data with a condition where I ignore the distance requirement and instead pull users where u.online = 1 and include them all in the same dataset

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: because the distance is calculated, could you wrap the original query in a cte and then you can use a where clause to just pull records where u.online = 1 OR distance < 15?

Comment: Two separate `SELECT`s with a `UNION`, usually, but you can use `OR` in your `HAVING` clause also.

Comment: Thank you Marcus.  I ended up solving this through a UNION and it seems to be working perfectly.  Appreciate the tips from both of you